# How to make user automatically log out after authorizing app

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I use [Tweepy Oauth](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication) to get access_token. The user has to authorize me so he need to redirect to twitter site. After I get the access_token, it also means that the user is in login state.

Is there any method which will let user automatically log out after authorize me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user accepts manually the App, he have to connect himself, and accept, then disconnect.
If the app/library handles itself the token by connecting the user automatically, the user won't be "really" connected in his own browser, because the session cookie is browser-specific.

Comment: Yes, the user accepts the App manually. So...there is no way that the app can disconnect on behalf of user?

Comment: I am thinking about using mechanize to open an url (logout url) automatically

Comment: If the user uses his own browser to accept the app, he has to disconnect itself, because your app can't go directly in user browser parameters.
Consider using "Basic Authentification" which simulates user action (connecting, the accepting the app) but needs username and password